# Registrar datos en una clave foranea de una tabla en una base de datos mysql desde mi aplicacion Android

Tags: php, mysql, android

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que tengo varias tablas en la base de datos mysql.

Tabla padre (idpadre(PK), usuario, nombre, contraseña).

Tabla hijo (idhijo, nombre, fechanacimiento, idpadre (FK).

Tabla tareas (idtarea(PK), desctarea, edadtarea, ptostarea, idhijo(FK), idpadre(FK).

Desde la aplicacion Android, realizo un registro en la tabla padres y posteriormente un login. Una vez está un padre loggeado, puede añadir un hijo o una tarea a la base de datos desde la aplicacion android. La inserción de datos se hace de forma correcta, pero en los campos foraneos de cada tabla no me inserta ningun registro.

Por ejemplo, si el padre con id=1 crea un hijo con id=2, en la columna idpadre(FK) de la tabla hijo, no se me inserta el id=1, con lo cual no puedo filtrar despues solo a los hijos que tienen el padre con ese id.

El archivo php que conecta la aplicacion con la base de datos para este caso concreto es el siguiente:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $nombre_hijo = $_POST['nombre_hijo'];
    $fecha_nac = $_POST['fecha_nac'];

    require_once 'conexion.php';

    //$fecha_nac = date('Y-m-d',$fecha_nac); //Lo comvierte a formato de fecha en MySQL

    $sql = "INSERT INTO hijos(nombre_hijo,fecha_nac)VALUES('$nombre_hijo','$fecha_nac')";


    if(mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){
        $response["success"] = "1";
        $response["message"] ="El hijo se ha registrado.";
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }else{

        $response["success"] = "2";
        $response["message"] = "Hijo no creado";

        echo("Error" .$conexion->error);

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }

}

?>
```

No se como modificar la consulta sql en el archivo para que me inserte el campo idpadre en la tabla hijos una vez loggeado el padre.

Esta es la tabal hijos con su clave foranea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta otra es la tabla padres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se donde puede estar el error. Lo mismo me pasa con las claves foraneas de la tabla tareas. No se registra el id del padre que la crea en la aplicacion.

Estoy intentando buscar soluciones por la web y no encuentro nada, mas que hacer inner join para unir dos tablas. Pero al ser un INSERT la consulta sql, no se que puedo hacer.

Este es el archivo php con el que realizo el login

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    require_once 'conexion.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM padres WHERE usuario='$usuario' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    if($result->num_rows==0){
        $response["success"] = "TRUE";
        $response["message"] ="El usuario no se ha encontrado o los datos son incorrectos.";
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }else{
        $padre = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $response["success"] = "FALSE";
        $response["message"] = "Login realizado";
        $response["padre"] = $padre;
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }

}

?>
```

Codigo java en android estudio para la realizacion del login del padre

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etusuario, etcontras;
    private Button btnentrar;

    private String URL="https://appyay.000webhostapp.com/logincolores.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etusuario=findViewById(R.id.etusuario);
        etcontras=findViewById(R.id.etcontras);
        btnentrar=findViewById(R.id.btnentrar);



        btnentrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usuario = etusuario.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = etcontras.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!usuario.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty()) {
                    Login(usuario, password);
                } else {
                    etusuario.setError("Inserte un usuario");
                    etcontras.setError("Inserte una contraseña");

                }
            }


        });
    }

    private void Login(final String usuario, final String password) {


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        String success=jsonObject.getString("success");

                        if(success.equals("FALSE")){

                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login realizado. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);


                        }else if(success.equals("TRUE")){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No ha podido entrar. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            },new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ERROR" +error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            ){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
                    parametros.put("usuario",usuario);
                    parametros.put("password",password);
                    return parametros;

                }
            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Comment: Que método usas para hacer login? De ahi puedes obtener el id para el padre

Comment: Edito la publicacion y añado el archivo que uso para el login

Comment: Comprendo, ademas de que deberias tener TRUE y FALSE en el lado correcto, ¿cómo identificas al usuario logeado en el archivo que genera al hijo?

Comment: Creo que ese es mi error. Una vez logeado, doy por hecho que ese padre que ha hecho login, es el que esta creando al hijo. pero imagino que tendre que usar algun otro método para relacionarlos. No se si al INSERT que realizo en la cracion de los hijos, tengo que ponerle alguna condicion para que se registre el id del padre.

Comment: Si, el `Insert` debe tener cambios, pero debes primero desde tu app enviar el dato del padre logeado, al menos el id y con eso puedes guardarlo.

Comment: ¿Como podría hacer eso? Es decir, si realiza el login y accede a la app, como hago para que la app sepa que está dentro de un padre y no de otro? Ando un poco perdida. Voy a añadir el código que tengo en android del login. A ver si con ello puedes ayudarme.

Comment: Se supone que en `logincolores.php` obtienes el `id` del padre ¿no? Entonces, cuando mandas a hacer el `INSERT` del hijo, junto con los datos del mismo debes enviar también el `id` del padre para que se inserte en la tabla, de ese modo el hijo queda registrado como perteneciente a ese padre. El problema es que al hacer el `INSERT` no estás mandando desde Android al servidor el id del padre.

Comment: Otro consejo: deberías usar consultas preparadas, el código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. Cualquier usuario mal intencionado podría atacar al servidor desde la aplicación con una facilidad pasmosa. Y ese ataque puede consistir en borrar/modificar/obtener datos de cualquier tipo, hasta manipular archivos del sistema, según la capacidad y malignidad del atacante.

Comment: A ver, tendría que hacer un INSERT en el archivo de CREARHIJO en el que incluya la variable del id_padre, ¿no?. Pero para ello imagino que tendre que añadir un edittext en Android para el que propio padre ponga su id y asi se asocien ambos. La idea es que cuando tenga que registrar a su hijo en la aplicacion, no tenga que poner ningun dato suyo, puesto que la app deberia saber dentro de que usuario padre está.  Sobre lo de las consultas preparadas, lo se. Es mas recomendable usarlas, pero es para un proyecto de un ciclo y no me da tiempo a aprender más sobre el tema ese. Lo ire aprendiendo :)

Comment: Esto no es correcto: *«Pero para ello imagino que tendre que añadir un edittext en Android para el que propio padre ponga su id y asi se asocien ambos.»*, lo correcto y lógico es esto: *«puesto que la app deberia saber dentro de que usuario padre está»...* En efecto, la App debe saber cuál es el `id` del padre y mandarlo al hacer la inserción del hijo. La pregunta que te hago es precisamente esa: **¿se conoce el `id` del padre, de qué forma se conoce? Si no se conoce, debes hacer que se conozca y mandarlo al insertar al hijo.** Creo que te estás liando entre dos conceptos contradictorios.

Comment: Si. Tengo mucho lio de conceptos con todo esto. Estoy aprendiendo muchas cosas nuevas en poco tiempo a base de errores. ¿Como puedo conocer e id_padre dentro de la activity de crearhijo? ¿Una vez conocido, como realizo el INSERT para que incluya dicho id? Seguro que es muy sencillo pero llevo con esto tres días y no soy capaz de dar con una solucion. Tampoco se si tengo alguna restriccion puesta mal en mi base de datos. Gracias por intentar ayudarme.

Comment: Una duda, si guardo el inicio de sesion en un SharedPreferences, seria suficiente para almacenar ese id del padre en la tabla hijos? O la preferencias es algo secundario que no tiene nada que ver con esto?

Comment: Imaginemos que el padre se loguea mediante una contraseña (es lo que intuyo viendo tu código). Al loguearse puedes recuperar su id y guardarlo en SharedPreferences o donde quieras y cuando se vaya a insertar el hijo extraes el id del padre de dónde lo tengas y lo mandas a la inserción junto con los datos del hijo. Esa es la lógica a implementar, teniendo eso claro podrás decidir de la mejor manera la forma de persistir el id del padre, dependiendo del contexto.

Comment: de acuerdo a lo que explicas las relaciones están confusas: * al parecer sólo el padre genera tareas y las genera para un hijo, en ese caso el idpadre en la tabla tareas no es necesario, porque a través del hijo llegas al padre. * sino si pueden asignarse tareas tanto a padres como a hijos todos deberían estar en la misma tabla, con un campo (numérico) que indique quienes pertenecen al mismo grupo familiar y otro campo que indique quien es el padre. No es concreto a lo que preguntas pero espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Estoy intentado solucionar esto ultimo que me has comentado. Creo que tengo algo mas claro los conceptos, aunque me sigue dando errores. Cuando tenga una solución clara la pondre por aqui. Gracias

Comment: Efectivamente, solo el padre puede crear tareas para asignarlas a sus hijos. Puede que tenga un error de diseño de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Solucione esto.

Cree una clase SessionManager donde guarde los datos en SharedPreferences.

En la actividad para crear tareas, premios o hijos creo un HasMap donde recupero el ID de la clase SessionManager. Con esto ya tengo el id del padre.

Modifique los archivos php para que inserte en la tabla el id_padre.